# How does a method know which object to work on?

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I am wording this properly, but I am confused about how a method can tell which object it is working on. Or another way to reword this is how can you specify a method to work on certain object?

For example, if I create two objects that work with some kind of array. Let's say obj1 and obj2. If I then implement some kind of add() method that would add some value to the array. How can I differentiate from obj1.add(E value) versus obj2.add(E value).

I've tried creating an array but the problem is that obj1.add() and obj2.add() would edit the same array, and I want them to work separately. In the constructor it gives the array a size.

```
class Example{
    int arr[];
    Example(int a) {
       int size = a;
       arr = new int[a];
    }

    add(int value) {
       // adds some value to the array
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Example obj1 = new Example(5);
       Example obj2 = new Example(10);

       obj1.add(1);
       obj2.add(2);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create different objects that would work on its own array? I'm extremely confused because add would always modify arr and there's only one array.

Comment: How did you infer that both objects work on the same array? As an aside: your code does not compile; method `add` is missing its return type.

Comment: I'm assuming that's one of the issues and the solution would be to create a second array, but if I wanted to create x amount of objects/array then I wasn't sure how the scope would be of the array for any additional methods.

Comment: @zetsuboupaul You use `this` to access the members of the object you are currently working on, while inside a method of such object.

Comment: Well... long story short: the two objects do, in fact, operate on separate arrays. You can verify this through `System.out.println(obj1.arr == obj2.arr);` which will print `false`.

Comment: In other words, if I were to create some kind of print() method that would print the contents of the array, and I tried obj1.print() and obj2.print(), the output would in theory be different?

Edit: To add on, in other words I wouldn't need to create any additional arrays? The constructor would be sufficient to create as many "Example" objects as I would like and work on them as needed separately from one another?

Comment: [Not only in theory](https://ideone.com/FiC4ab)

Comment: @zetsuboupaul When you create a new `Example` object the constructor of that class will create a new `int` array and reference it inside the field `arr`. When you create another `Example` object this instance will create another `int` array and reference it. So in total, you have four objects: Two `Example` objects which have both an `int` array (one of size 5, one of size 10).

Comment: That helps clear up my confusion, thank you to both. For some reason I was under the impression they'd work on the same array.

Comment: They would if the array were defined `static`.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a real beginner question, but I'll try to explain it as simple as possible as it can be hard to wrap your mind around when you get started.

When you do

```
   Example obj1 = new Example(5);
   Example obj2 = new Example(10);
```

You are making two objects in the RAM of your PC.
They each get an individual memory address and take up as much space as they need.

You can see an Object in your RAM as a house on a street.

```
   Example Benny = new Example(5);
   Example Jacob = new Example(10);
```

The street now has two houses. Benny and Jacob.

Benny's house number is 105
Jacob's house number is 42

Their houses were built exactly the same. The only difference is that Benny can accept 5 guests, and Jacob can accept 10 guests.

When a taxi comes by to add a guest, he gets the command, add a guest to Street number 105. The taxi drives to street number 105, ignores any houses that are not number 105, and adds the guest to that house.

He then goes back to dispatch and gets the command, add a guest to Street number 42. He then drives to street number 42, adds the guest to that house.

Due to the have different address, there's never a mix up to which house guests are added to which house. The houses do not share guest places in this setup.

I added a diagran below, to show that they have different lists, and different flows.

[image: schematic describing what happens]

I hope this helps you a bit in understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is easy to do. You can maintain arrays in two different objects as below:

```
class Example{
    int arr[];
    Example(int a)
    {
       int size = a;
       this.arr= new int[a];
    }

    void add(int value)
    {
       // adds some value to the array
       //your logic to insert values in the array
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Example obj1 = new Example(5);
       Example obj2 = new Example(10);

       obj1.add(1);
       obj2.add(2);
       obj1.add(3);
       obj2.add(4);
       for(int i=0;i<obj1.arr.length;i++){ //obj1.arr is used to access the array of that object
         System.out.println(obj1.arr[i]); //just for printing purpose
       }
       for(int j=0;j<obj2.arr.length;j++){
         System.out.println(obj2.arr[j]); //just for printing purpose
       }

    }
}
```

In the above code, you can use **this** keyword with the array (this.arr) to maintain the arrays in different objects differently.

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

`public class Example{
    int arr[];
    int currentElementsInArray=0;//this is the number of elements currently in the array

```
Example(int a) {
   int size = a;
   arr = new int[a];
}

public void add(int value) {
   // adds some value to the array
   this.arr[this.currentElementsInArray++]= value; /*this will add the incoming element to the next
    vacant position of the array*/
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Example obj1 = new Example(5);
   Example obj2 = new Example(10);

   obj1.add(1);
   obj1.add(1);
   obj1.add(5);

   obj2.add(2);
   obj2.add(4);
   obj2.add(22);

   //prints the elements in the first array

   for(int i=0 ; i < obj1.currentElementsInArray ; i++){
   System.out.println(obj1.arr[i]);
   }

   //prints the elements in the second array

    for(int j=0 ; j < obj2.currentElementsInArray ; j++){
   System.out.println(obj2.arr[j]);
   }

}
```

}`

Run this. Two arrays will be created separately for the two objects.